# How can I render a component if a user moves out of a region?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am developing an application with react native and [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps) in which I want to render a component only when the user leaves the US region. It's not clear to me how I can do this, how do I know if the current region is no longer within a specific radius/bounds i.e:

```
if (region !== USARegion) {
  return <MyComponent />
}
```

Comment: This may help https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/356#issuecomment-515694070

Answer (score 0):

Just to briefly explain how you would go about doing this:

You would need to use a listener to monitor the user's coordinates, I used expo location

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/

to get the coordinates use:

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
```

then in your useEffect you need to listen for these changes in location

```
  useEffect(() => {

//other functions here

  },[location])
```

Note: you will probably need to store these locations somewhere to track changes. I recommend using a firebase realtime database

Then to get the actual region based on the coordinates you have gathered, I suggest using a this API: http://www.geonames.org/

It is fairly lightweight and simple to use.

After you've got the new region you can run your above if statement to check if the region is not USA